# Convergence condition Newton method for quadratic system of equations

Tags: analysis, reference-request, dynamical-systems, newton-raphson

So suppose I want to solve a system of $n$ quadratic equations given by $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ using the Newton method, $x_{n+1} = x_n - J^{-1}(x_n)f(x_n)$. Do there exist general results on the coefficients of $f(x)$ which guarantee convergence of the Netwon iterator?

For quadratic $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ there exist some general results but I was curious if this has been studied in an $n$-dimensional setting.

Comment: One can express any polynomial system as a (much) higher-dimensional system of quadratic equations. So if such a result existed, it would find rather wide attention.

Comment: You might have a misconception. Every regular solution point has some basin of quadratic convergence around it. Thus the question is not convergence per se, but how large these sets are and finding starting points in or close to these basins.